# Errors occur when build Zeppelin

Tags: maven-3, apache-zeppelin

I build Zeppelin from `git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin` using `mvn clean package -U -DskipTests`. But the console gives me the following error message <`Failed to execute goal on project zeppelin-phoenix: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-phoenix:jar:0.6.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact sqlline:sqlline:jar:1.1.8 in public (http://maven.dev.sh.ctripcorp.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/public) -> [Help 1]`>, I am trying to figure out how to solve. But it seems useless. Can anyone help me and work around it ?

```
[INFO] Zeppelin ........................................... SUCCESS [  3.383 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Interpreter .............................. SUCCESS [  3.688 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Zengine .................................. SUCCESS [  2.334 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark dependencies ....................... SUCCESS [ 21.198 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Spark .................................... SUCCESS [  5.601 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Markdown interpreter ..................... SUCCESS [  0.243 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Angular interpreter ...................... SUCCESS [  0.169 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Shell interpreter ........................ SUCCESS [  0.160 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Hive interpreter ......................... SUCCESS [  1.103 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Phoenix Interpreter ............... FAILURE [  0.154 s]
[INFO] Zeppelin: PostgreSQL interpreter ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Tajo interpreter ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Flink .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Apache Ignite interpreter ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Kylin interpreter ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Lens interpreter ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Cassandra ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Elasticsearch interpreter ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: web Application .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Server ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Zeppelin: Packaging distribution ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 38.552 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-13T18:23:47+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 54M/807M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project zeppelin-phoenix: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-phoenix:jar:0.6.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact sqlline:sqlline:jar:1.1.8 in public (http://maven.dev.sh.ctripcorp.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/public) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sqlline:sqlline:jar:1.1.8 is served from conjar repo., so you may also have to mirror conjar to internal infra if you're restricted to connect internet.

sqlline:sqlline:jar:1.1.9 is served from maven repo., so you can also exclude it and manually add dependency sqlline:sqlline:1.1.9.